# How to set UTF8 in PDO OCI // PHP

Tags: php, pdo, utf-8, oracle-call-interface

I want to connect my Oracle SQL and already set utf8,
but there still got garbled text when I select or insert something.

Here is my code:

```
define("DB_HOST", "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                            (HOST= IP)
                            (PORT=1521))
                            (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=IETDB)));
                            charset = utf8
    ");
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Vote to reopen as the dupe does not answer this question; specifically with regard to PDO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this by modifying the connection string since that's not supported.

As documented on the [`oci_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) manual page, the fourth parameter specifies the charset:

```
oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF-8');
```

This tells OCI to expect you to provide strings in UTF8 format and to provide resultsets in UTF8, converted from the database charset. From the manual:

> Determines the character set used by the Oracle Client libraries. The character set does not need to match the character set used by the database. If it doesn't match, Oracle will do its best to convert data to and from the database character set. Depending on the character sets this may not give usable results. Conversion also adds some time overhead.
>
> If not specified, the Oracle Client libraries determine a character set from the NLS_LANG environment variable.
>
> Passing this parameter can reduce the time taken to connect.

If you're using PDO_OCI the charset can be appended to the DSN, again [as documented](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php):

```
new \PDO('oci:dbname=' . $conn_string . ';charset=UTF8', $username, $password);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I insert " export NLS_LANG="TRADITIONAL CHINESE_TAIWAN.UTF8"  " in 'envvars' file which under XAMPP, then solve the problem!

Comment: If "UTF-8" doesn't work for anyone, try "AL32UTF8".

Comment: @wast finally, but finally something that works, thanks!